# Create a data extension that contains a list of subscrubers, the number of emails they have been sent, and how many opens and clicks they have?

Tags: automationstudio

I've been trying to produce a list of unengaged subscribers i.e people who have been sent multiple messages but have not opened or clicked any of them. When looking through my SFMC account I discovered that someone had previously made a DE that looks like this:

[image]

However I have no idea how this was made? Do you have any idea how I could replicate this DE?

Comment: they did this with a query, I would like in query activities with this DE as a target